# Hosting an ASP.NET web application backed by Neo4j

Tags: asp.net, mono, hosting, neo4j, graph-databases

I already have ASP.NET hosting, but I'm not sure how to run my application off Neo4j, since it requires a Java stack.

It seems my only options are:

- Get separate Java/Linux hosting, and install Neo4J there, utilizing it as a database server.
- Get Neo4J-as-a-service, (akin to what MongoHQ does for MongoDB users) but I haven't had any luck finding providers. Any advice here?
- Move my whole application to Mono and then put it all on Java/Linux hosting and install Neo4j.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is such a thing very much indeed. We have just put Neo4j hosted in Windows Azure and as such it may naturally back an ASP.NET solution or any other front end solution that you might want to have!

Besides it is very easy to communicate with the Neo4j server from .NET since it speaks over HTTP using REST. It's as natural to speak to it as it is to speak with Windows Azure Storage.

http://neo4j.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more how did you install it to Azure? What service are you using? Thanks.

Comment: This was a while back. We used a CloudService to host the process running our server. Installing it involved downloading and unzipping both a java runtime and the server. Today I would instead use a Linux VM host Neo4j in Windows Azure I think. That would make more sense and probably be both a smoother install and offer better performance (due to the fact that this is the best environment for this java based server).